# Why am I seeing "no connection adapters found" when trying to use results as a variable, but not while trying to print?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests, gspread

Hope I am asking this the right way - just confused with what's going on: I have my working script (below).  I'm trying to take the URLs from a spreadsheet, rather than copy and paste them in - basically, creating urlsA from column N on the sheet connected.

I've tested it out - I can print urlsA to terminal no problem, so I know the Sheet connection is working.  I just can't seem to use them when I try to run the full script.  I'm receiving this error:

[image: Error]

Working code (before pulling links from Google Sheet):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv

profilesA = []
urlsA = ['https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=2&stats_player_seq=-100',
         'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=6&stats_player_seq=-100',
         'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=7&stats_player_seq=-100',
         'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=17&stats_player_seq=-100',
         'https://stats.ncaa.org/player/game_by_game?game_sport_year_ctl_id=15881&id=15881&org_id=23&stats_player_seq=-100']


for urlA in urlsA:
    req = requests.get(urlA, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profileA in soup.select('.smtext > a[href^="/contests/"]'):
        profileA = 'https://stats.ncaa.org'+profileA.get('href')
        profilesA.append(profileA)

profilesB = []
urlsB = profilesA

for urlB in urlsB:
    req = requests.get(urlB, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profileB in soup.select('a[href^="/game/play_by_play/"]'):
        profileB = 'https://stats.ncaa.org'+profileB.get('href')
        profilesB.append(profileB)

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = profilesB
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for url in urls:
    gameId = url.split('/')[-1]
    r = s.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    for df in dfs:
        if len(df.columns) > 2:
            if df.iloc[0, 2] == 'Score':
                df[4] = df[3]
                df[[2, 3]] = df[2].str.split('-', expand=True)

        df.to_csv('2022test.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

Broken code: "No connection adapters were found" error:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import csv
from unittest import skip
import json
import gspread

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1cEQlPB_ykJrucnbGgKhlKj49RdLNAzeO6fiO2gkQeNU')
wk = sh.worksheet("Team Select")
profilesA = []
ShUrls = wk.batch_get(('N3:N',))[0]
urlsA = ShUrls


for urlA in urlsA:
    req = requests.get(urlA, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    time.sleep(5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profileA in soup.select('.smtext > a[href^="/contests/"]'):
        profileA = 'https://stats.ncaa.org'+profileA.get('href')
        profilesA.append(profileA)

profilesB = []
urlsB = profilesA

for urlB in urlsB:
    req = requests.get(urlB, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    for profileB in soup.select('a[href^="/game/play_by_play/"]'):
        profileB = 'https://stats.ncaa.org'+profileB.get('href')
        profilesB.append(profileB)

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

urls = profilesB
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
for url in urls:
    gameId = url.split('/')[-1]
    r = s.get(url)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    for df in dfs:
        if len(df.columns) > 2:
            if df.iloc[0, 2] == 'Score':
                df[4] = df[3]
                df[[2, 3]] = df[2].str.split('-', expand=True)

        df.to_csv('2022test.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd inspect this line:

```
ShUrls = wk.batch_get(('N3:N',))[0]
```

As you might be pulling a list of lists, hence, this line breaks

```
    req = requests.get(urlA, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
```

with the `No connection adapters were found` error as a list is not a valid URL.

Comment: hmmmm I think I understand -- N3:N is a list of URLs -- that's ultimately the list of URLs from my first script that I wanted to replace.  I thought I could just use the Sheet as the source.  I had the same set up in a similar script using a list of URLs in a Sheet as a URL list, and it worked fine.  Just confused on this one

Answer (score 0):

Needed to flatten urlsA after seeing it was an array of arrays.  Using this, then calling flatten fixed the issue:

```
  def flatten(l):
        fl = []
        for sublist in l:
            for item in sublist:
                fl.append(item)
    
        return fl
```